# LSTM in pytorch works even with wrong input size

Tags: pytorch, lstm

```
import torch
import torch.autograd as autograd
import torch.nn as nn

lstm = nn.LSTM(3, 2)
input = torch.randn(6, 4, 5)
lstm(input)
```

The above code does not raise an error, but the input size of 5 is different from the input size of the LSTM, which is 3.

I think it should raise an error.

Interestingly, if one provides the hidden input, it will raise the error as expected

```
import torch
import torch.autograd as autograd
import torch.nn as nn

lstm = nn.LSTM(3, 2)
hidden = (torch.rand(6, 4, 2), torch.rand(6, 4, 2))
input = torch.randn(6, 4, 5)
lstm(input,hidden)[0].shape
```

The above codes lead to
RuntimeError: input.size(-1) must be equal to input_size. Expected 3, got 5

Comment: The first code example throws the expected error when I run it. `RuntimeError: input.size(-1) must be equal to input_size. Expected 3, got 5`